Docker pull image before building to enable better caching
I have a docker multi stage build which takes ~1.5hours to run.
I am building the image in a GitLab CI pipeline and pushing it to a container repository. The problem is because of the way my CI pipeline works, there is no caching of builds and everything must be run from scratch each time.
Is it possible to pull the previous version of an image from the container registry before trying to build the new one? and in doing so benefit from the caching of previous stages.

You can use --cache-from argument in docker build command, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/docker_layer_caching.html

Perfect, thank you :)
